# How to change NgModule configuration at runtime

Tags: angular, angular2-services

There are some modules that expose their service configuration, for example:

- `AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)`,
- `StoreModule.provideStore(reducer)`,
- `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)`...

How would I reconfigure one of these at runtime? For example, user selects one of two links and different module is lazy loaded and configured differently... How can I pass data to this new NgModule?

All I can think of is to put something in global scope and read it from there, but... doesn't feel right :)

Answer (score 2):

Providers can't be modified after the injector was created.

You can create a service that provides different instances depending on status.

```
@Injectable()
class ProviderService {
  constructor(injector:Injector) {}

  set firebaseConfig(firebaseConfig) {
    let resolvedProviders = ReflectiveInjector.resolve([AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)]);
    this.childInjector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolvedProviders, this.injector);    
  }

  get firebase ():AngularFireModule {
    return this.childInjector.get(AngularFireModule);
  }
}
```

and then use it like

```
class MyComponentOrService {
  constructor(provider:ProviderService) {}

  changeFirebase() {
    this.provider.firebaseConfig = ...;
    this.fb = this.provider.firebase;
  }

  doSomething() {
    this.fb.xxx();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is perfect! Very cool, you made my day :P Just a few things to clarify: where does `let this.childInjector = ...` come from? And `AngularFireModule.initializeApp(this.firebaseConfig)]` should be just *firebaseConfig*, the argument? I'd have to write this for every service I wish to reconfigure (although I don't expect I'll have many, anyway)?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistakes. I miss syntax highlighting in StackOverflow editor ;-) I updated the code.

Comment: Should I put this in lazy loaded module's `prodivers: [ProviderService]`? Will Angular dispose of this provider for lazy loaded module? Do I need to do any cleanup (and if so, how)?

Comment: If yo add it to a lazy loaded module then only services and components within that lazy loaded part of your application will be able to inject it. If you add it to the root module or any other non-lazy loaded module, then it will be available for your entire application. There is no cleanup necessary if the provided modules (AngularFireModule, StoreModule, ... don't need any cleanup but I assume they don't).

Comment: Didn't have a chance to try this until now - concept is good for providers, but these are `ModuleWithProviders`. When I do `this.provider.firebase` I'm getting an empty wrapper object `AngularFireModule`

Comment: If I `return this.childInjector.get(AngularFire);` I get same instance with `console.log(this.provider.firebase, this.af)` even though I used different configurations. Module configures it [like this](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/angularfire2.ts#L116-L127).

Comment: When `firebaseConfig()` is called a new injector is created with new providers, therefore I can't explain why you get the same instance. Do you provide `AngularFireModule` anywhere else in your application?

Comment: Yea, I have it in other module (loaded before this one). I should use this ProviderService there too, I guess?

Comment: Exactly. . . . . . .. . .

Comment: Couldn't make it work, I was on a right track, but `AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)` sets up too many dependencies/providers, so I'd have to provide them all individually. Gets complicated, and I can't use AngularFire directly in other places... too many things to keep track of... I used `firebase.initializeApp` directly to make 2nd connection, that solved my immediate problem. But thanks for this great pattern, I'm sure I'll use it in other places (;

Comment: I also don't have more ideas because I don't understand the problem well enough. I haven't used Angularfire myself yet.