# Changing provider in tests using ReflectiveInjector

Tags: angular

Is it possible to change provider using `ReflectiveInjector` in the same context? I need **`B`** to use different value in second test. A & B are services...

```ts
  let injector: ReflectiveInjector;
  beforeEach(() => {
    injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
      A, { provide: B, useValue: null }
    ]);
  });

  ...

  it('should be null', () => {
    const a = injector.get(A);
    expect(a.B).toBe(null)
  });

  it('shoul NOT be null', () => {
    const a = injector.get(A);
    // need something like this:
    // a.B = injector.CHANGE_B_PLEASE({ provide: B, useValue: true })
    expect(a.B).not.toBe(null)
  });
```

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Did something change in last 6 months, or are things same as [before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40035615/1876949)? Looks like I'm running into same problems again (;

Comment: Can you create plunker based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40032954/how-to-change-ngmodule-configuration-at-runtime ? The code here and in previous question are completely different. You can only create new injector where you can specify parent injector.

Comment: @yurzui Code is different, but idea is the same - replacing one provider with another. For tests I made `setup(value) => { /* does what beforeEach did */ }`; I was just wondering if there's better way to do it with `ReflectiveInjector`.

Comment: There is only one way that was written by Günter in your previous question

Comment: `The answer is grounded in a fundamental characteristic of the Angular dependency-injection system. An injector can add providers until it's first used. Once an injector starts creating and delivering services, its provider list is frozen; no new providers are allowed.` https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#why-does-lazy-loading-create-a-child-injector-

Comment: Check also docs https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/packages/docs/di

Comment: [Transient Dependencies](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/docs/di/di.md#transient-dependencies) offers solution similar to mine in the answer. I'll stick with that (: Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for testing:

```ts
  let injector: ReflectiveInjector;
  setup((value) => {
    injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
      A, { provide: B, useValue: value }
    ]);
  });

  ...

  it('should be null', () => {
    setup(null);
    const a = injector.get(A);
    expect(a.B).toBe(null)
  });

  it('shoul NOT be null', () => {
    setup(true);
    const a = injector.get(A);
    const b = injector.get(B);
    expect(a.B).toBe(true)
    expect(b).toBe(true)
  });
```

For more information check:

- [DI Guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html)
- [Transient Dependencies](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/docs/di/di.md#transient-dependencies)
- [DI Advanced Topics](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/docs/di/di_advanced.md)